# How to generate a random number between 1000 and -1000 c++?

Tags: c++, random

I have to code guess the number game but I don't know how to generate the random number. The random function only generates negative numbers.

The code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int N=rand()%1000+-1000;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Using a [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)?

Comment: Negative numbers, like, tend to appear when you have 1000 subtracted from a random number from 0 to 999 =)

Answer (score 2):

> The code that I have so far only generates negative numbers.

The maximum of `rand()%1000` is `999`. If you add `-1000` to it, it will be always negative. Try `rand() % 2001 - 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, I'm away from my computer and can't test it though:

```
(rand()%(max-min))+min;
```

Answer (score 1):

The range of [-1000,1000] has 2001 options (assuming you want to include both boundaries. You need to modulu `rand()`'s result by the width of the range, and add/subtract its beginning. I.e.:

```
int randomNumber = rand() % 2001 - 1000;
```